# How to emit socket io variable instead "\"text\"" text notation

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, arduino, esp32

## Hi

I'm learning to use websocket client in arduino ESP32 board. I can receive and emit text in this form, ""text"" as i can show here.

```
socketIO.emit("emitevent", "\"this is a message from the client\"");
```

or

```
char* Name = "\"Carlos\"";
webSocket.emit("newEmitEvent", Name);
```

I would like to charge a variable String to send it but i cant find the way. For example,

```
 String Values;
 Values = 00:a3:45;

 webSocket.emit("newEmitEvent", Values);
```

But I can't see how to do it,

Can you help me,

please?

Thanks

Comment: i'd tryng thinks like
''"\" + Values + \""';
but dont

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with,

```
Values += """\"";

Values += 00:a3:45;
Values += "," // if i'm in a loop

Values += "\"";
```

But, it is a clean solution?

Thanks,